Generate Tags for a text given
I am trying to build an API using flask which will extract the text from a url given and generate valid tags for that text. Say for example, the text is for a recipe of chicken curry, valid tags can be recipe, Indian Cuisine, food etc.
I have tried nltk library, TF-IDF vectorizer etc, but all of them are analysing maximum frequency of the words, not generating new words.
Does any one have any solution for this problem.
I have also tried using gtp2 module, but the output is not what I am expecting
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer, GPT2LMHeadModel
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

# Load pre-trained GPT-2 model and tokenizer
model_name = 'gpt2-medium'
tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained(model_name)

def fetch_text_from_url(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()  # Raise HTTPError for bad responses
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        
        # Find all paragraphs and concatenate their text
        paragraphs = soup.find_all('p')
        text = ' '.join([para.get_text() for para in paragraphs])
        
        return text
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error fetching content from {url}: {str(e)}")
        return None
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error parsing content from {url}: {str(e)}")
        return None

def generate_tags(text, max_length=20, num_return_sequences=3):
    try:
        # Create a prompt to generate tags
        prompt = "Tags for this text: "

        # Tokenize the input text and prompt
        input_ids = tokenizer.encode(prompt + text, return_tensors='pt')

        # Generate tags using GPT-2 model
        output = model.generate(
            input_ids,
            max_length=max_length + len(input_ids[0]),
            num_return_sequences=num_return_sequences,
            num_beams=5,
            no_repeat_ngram_size=2,
            early_stopping=True
        )

        # Decode generated tags
        tags = []
        for seq in output:
            decoded_seq = tokenizer.decode(seq, skip_special_tokens=True).strip()
            # Extract tags from the generated text
            tags.extend([t.strip() for t in decoded_seq.split() if t.startswith('#')])

        return tags
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error generating tags: {str(e)}")
        return None

@app.route('/generate_tags', methods=['POST'])
def generate_tags_api():
    data = request.get_json()
    url = data.get('url')
    if not url:
        return jsonify({'error': 'URL is required'}), 400

    try:
        text = fetch_text_from_url(url)
        if not text:
            return jsonify({'error': 'Failed to fetch content from URL'}), 500
        
        tags = generate_tags(text)
        if tags:
            return jsonify({'tags': tags})
        else:
            return jsonify({'error': 'Failed to generate tags from URL'}), 500
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 500

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=8000, debug=True)


nltk library, TF-IDF vectorizer etc. are statistical models and have limited capabilities. You are looking for something that can analyses a text and output a list of relevant tags. This task is more suited for LLMs.
Unfortunately, because page content can be quite long, you will need an LLM with a large context window, hence an heavy one. Make sure that GPT-2 is suited for this task. Could you provide further information as to why its output is not what you are expecting? You could try to change your prompt, or add more context to it.
